# Gatling Time Extraction From Response Body

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

- **I am completely new to Gatling/Scala.**

I have a scenario to execute. Here it goes:

-->Change the shift timings of the employees.

For the above, I am able to script/code the flow. However, I have a challenge:
-> I need to extract the "new" time values from the response and check if that matches with the "new" time values being passed through the parameter (csv) file.

**Approach/logic**: Extract the date values from the response body and compare that with the date value that has been provided in the csv file.

Sample Response:

```
{
   "employeeId":"xxxxxx",
   "schedules":
   [
   {
  "date":"2019-11-25",
:   :   :   "schedules":
:   :   :   [
:   :   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   :   "employeeId":"xxxxxx",
:   :   :   :   :   "laborWeekStartDate":"2019-11-25",  //New edited time
:   :   :   :   :   "laborWeekEndDate":"2019-12-01",    //New edited time
:   :   :   :   :   "schedules":
:   :   :   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   :   :   "startTime":"2019-11-25T18:15:00.000Z",
:   :   :   :   :   :   "endTime":"2019-11-25T23:45:00.000Z",
:   :   :   :   :   :   "departmentId":xxxxx,
:   :   :   :   :   :   "departmentName":"abc",
:   :   :   :   :   :   "lastModifiedTimestamp":"2019-12-11T09:22:44.000Z",
:   :   :   :   :   :   "breakDetails":
:   :   :   :   :   :   [
:   :   :   :   :   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   "startTime":"2019-11-25T21:00:00.000Z",
:   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   "endTime":"2019-11-25T21:15:00.000Z",
:   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   "type":"break"
:   :   :   :   :   :   :   }
:   :   :   :   :   :   ]
:   :   :   :   :   }
:   :   :   :   }
:   :   :   ]
:   :   }
```

Here, in the below, the right-handside values need to be extracted and compared with the values provided in the csv file.

**"startTime":"2019-11-25T18:15:00.000Z",**

**"endTime":"2019-11-25T23:45:00.000Z",**

Please help in performing the above. A step-wise detailed explanation would be much appreciated considering I am totally new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: do you need to check multiple schedules for the employee? will you need to support multiple employees in a single response?

Comment: A little bit of self-advertising ;) in our company we have stopped using Gatling and created a new all-in-code perf testing library - https://github.com/encircled/jPut

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: *I will provide some useful links that should help you in achieving the task. If you will encounter any problems doing it, just post a new question*

1. In order to get a value from a JSON response, you could use a `jsonPath` [HTTP response body](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check#http-response-body). There is an example here, how value can be extracted and saved using this method :[JSON Path Usage for Gatling Tests](https://dzone.com/articles/json-path-usage-for-gatling-tests)
2. Reading values from CSV file is possible using a built-in `feeder` functionality: [CSV feeders](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder#csv-feeders) .Once you have the feeder added, you can reference a value using `${columnName}` There is an example here: [Step 03: Use dynamic data with Feeders and Checks](https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial#step-03-use-dynamic-data-with-feeders-and-checks). 
   *After this step you have both values in session. Then using scala language, you should be able to compare those values.* Getting a value from session happens using `session("variableName").as[String]`
3. For example, you could do a String comparision, if you first substring the value from csv. [Scala String comparision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297473/how-to-compare-two-strings-in-scala/26297743) Another option is like described here, which is really close to your requirement : [How to compare responses from http calls in gatling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911085/how-to-compare-responses-from-http-calls-in-gatling)

Good luck! :)